# USB camera (not RPi camera) isn't working on Android Things Preview 2

Tags: camera, usb, raspberry-pi3, android-things

There are samples of using *RPi* camera, but none of them are useful.
I have added permissions in the manifest file, but still the output is showing : `No cameras found`. Why?

```
02-22 19:24:42.936 2134-2134/com.example.androidthings.doorbell
    D/DoorbellActivity: Doorbell Activity created.
02-22 19:24:43.131 2134-2134/com.example.androidthings.doorbell
    I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
02-22 19:24:43.135 2134-2134/com.example.androidthings.doorbell
    D/DoorbellCamera: No cameras found
02-22 19:24:43.135 2134-2134/com.example.androidthings.doorbell
    W/DoorbellCamera: Cannot capture image. Camera not initialized.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [Hardware Support Matrix](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms) on the Developer Kits page, note that camera support is only provided over the CSI-2 interface, and not USB. The only media interface supported over USB in the current preview is audio record/playback.