# Is it possible to use multiple cameras with Raspberry pi 3 running AndroidThings?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Is there any way of using more than one camera on raspberry pi 3 running AndroidThings?

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402661/6950238) answer. It's actual for DP 5.1. And read [that](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell/issues/7) discussions.

Comment: Thank you, my intend is process real time video processing that has wider angle than pi cam sees.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible over the `CSI-2` interface and there is no `USB` camera support now (DP 5.1), but seems you can use several [VC0706 UART cameras](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/VC0706_UART_Camera_%EF%BC%88Supports_JPEG%EF%BC%89) (up to 5: 1 - over `UART` of Raspberry Pi 3 and other 4 - over `USB<->UART` converters, which supported [Developer Preview 3](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_3)). Also you can use several `SPI` cameras, or even shields, like [that](http://www.arducam.com/arducam-porting-raspberry-pi/arducam-pizero-3/) ([here](http://www.arducam.com/category/introduction/) is the overview). NB: in both (`UART` and `SPI`) cases you can't use normal API for image or video capture, you should implement camera (or shield) data protocol manually.