# Can we use USB camera with android things in RPi?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Is there support for using external USB camera in Android things(DP6)? 'Camera2Basic sample' works in the new release. What does that mean?

Comment: [Devunwired's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402661/6950238) still actual: camera supported oinly on NXP Pico i.MX7D and Raspberry Pi 3 both via CSI-2. "'Camera2Basic sample' works in the new release" - means that it really works (via CSI-2 interface).

Comment: Thanks. I want to interface my USB webcam with android things on RPi. Do you have any idea what can be a possible solution?

Comment: IMHO best solution: wait for USB Camera support (it is in feature request).