# hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) return false on Android things?

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, android-things

On **Android things** that is running on **Raspberry-Pi**

I tried to check if the camera available.. And it return false.

I use a camera device with a usb plug.(Camera has a usb port that can connect to the board)

I already put these in the manifest

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

The code to check the camera

```
getApplication().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) // return false
```

I tried to access the camera with this...

```
Camera c = Camera.open() // return null
```

In the setting, there is a camera preview that allow us to see the video that is being captured from the camera and I can see it.

Now how can I access the camera?

**EDIT**

I tried using a camera with **CSI-2 interface**, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB camera (not RPi camera) isn't working on Android Things Preview 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400687/usb-camera-not-rpi-camera-isnt-working-on-android-things-preview-2)

Comment: nope... I tested it. it doesn't work

Comment: It definitely works. Try this https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell or that https://github.com/BilalAndroidDev/AndroidThingsCamera or this https://github.com/harshithdwivedi/CameraDemoForAndroidThings as prototype.